# how to combine count and rate features in clustering

Tags: clustering, feature-selection, feature-engineering

In a hotel booking scenario, when we are using a clustering model to cluster people's booking behaviors. We have two out of 15 features:

Feature1: booking_counts_yearly, which indicates how many times bookings has specific customer made. e.g. customerA booked 25 times while customerB booked 2 times in 2017. CustomerA's `booking_counts_yearly=25` while customerB's `booking_counts_yearly=2`.

Feature2: booking_5_stars_rate, which indicates the portion of 5 star hotel bookings has been made by specific customers. e.g. customerA booked 25 times in total, 5 out of 25 bookings are 5 star hotels, then customerA's `booking_5_stars_rate` is `5/25=0.25`. CustomerB booked 2 times in total, none of the bookings is 5 star hotel, then customerB's `booking_5_stars_rate` is `0/2=0`.

Let's discuss this case:

1. Customer1 with `booking_counts_yearly=1`,
   `booking_5_stars_rate=100%(1)`
2. Customer2 with
   `booking_counts_yearly=1`, `booking_5_stars_rate=100%(1)`
3. Customer3
   with `booking_counts_yearly=1`, `booking_5_stars_rate=100%(1)`
4. Customer4 with `booking_counts_yearly=15`,
   `booking_5_stars_rate=100%(1)`
5. Customer5 with
   `booking_counts_yearly=100`, `booking_5_stars_rate=70%(0.7)`

In my case, customer 4 and customer 5 should be one cluster, it looks like they are like type of person: "made some bookings through the whole year and majority of times, they booked high-class hotels" while customer 1, 2, 3 are more like: "lived once a year, it happens to be 5 star".

What I should do in feature engineering to make sure these two type of persons are well separated. Currently the cluster my clustering model gives me, I have a lot of customer 1, 2, 3 (considered as noises) mixed with customer 4 in one single cluster.

Is there any way I can combine these two features so that my model would take the counts and rates both into consideration?

Comment: I disagree: customer 4 and 5 are very different, and don't cluster. They are both outliers. Or at least different clusters: one who books 2 or more times, but only 5 stars, and the other is the fraud cluster. Can you prove otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can map the booking_counts_yearly to a number of percentile classes.

E.g. low: less than 3 bookings, medium: 3-10 bookings, high: more than 10 bookings. Where 3 and 10 would be values that would split the population evenly (or by business purpose if necessary).

Similar you could partition the rating in percentiles, but that seems less relevant to me because of its nature.

--
Note, this could also depend on the machine learning/classification technique you are using. Decision trees may not need this at all, as they will determine the optimal partitioning by nature, while this normalization might be required for neural networks to function properly.

Answer (score 1):

It's not just about combining different feature types count/interval/ratio. Formally, you probably "only" need to treat all of them as ordinal data, and then you would supposedly be fine...

Pretty much any clustering algorithm is extremely sensitive to feature scaling. One star is not the same as one count. And there is no objective factor how to weight one versus the other.

The solution is to **abandon the idea of a "correct" clustering**. Consider any result to be just a suggestion. Study it, analyze it, debate it. Take only one of the clusters (not the entire clustering). Mix clusters  of different runs. Do *not* assume everybody is part of exactly one cluster, only some will cluster. Formalize single clusters. Verify each cluster with an experiment such as an A/B test. Etc.